# xforms - relevant with OR condition

Tags: xforms

(I'm just starting out with xforms)

I have a form with 10 integer entry fields and 1 text field
I'm trying to set a relevant criteria on a text field.
What I want to do is display the text field if and only if the value of one or more of the fields is higher than 18.

I believe I need an or condition in the relevant field, something like:
relevant="(/data/weight_group/weight1 > 18 || /data/weight_group/weight2 > 18)"

Obviously that's not exactly right, but I can't find anything even close on Google/Stack/etc., leading me to believe that I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
relevant="/data/weight_group/weight1 &lt; 18 or /data/weight_group/weight2 &gt; 18"
```

Some explanations:

- The value of relevant property is XPath expression. So you need to consult XPath documentation when something doesn't work.
- Logical operators in XPath are "and" and "or", not "&&" and "||".
- You need to escape < and > in XPath expressions as &lt; and &gt;, so that they don't mess up the XML structure. (Can someone confirm this?)

Comment: Sigh, yup. I tried 'or', escaping, and several other things, but never in the right combination, apparently. But yes, this solved the problem, thank you. To answer your issue of escaping, at the very least you need to escape <, I believe. I'm just going to escape everything from now on to decrease the chances of problems. Thanks again

Comment: If you are using XPath 2, you can also use the `lt` and `gt` operators, which you don't need to escape (that's why these operators were introduced).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the relevant property is a model property, that means it does not work on the controls.  Secondly it is updated via a bind element.

```
<model  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
  <instance>
     <data xmlns="">
        <weight_group>
           <weight1/><weight2/>
        </weight_group>
        <valid_weight>
     </data>
  </instance>
  <bind nodeset="/data/valid_weight" relevant="../weight_group/weight1 &lt; 18 or ../weight_group/weight2 &gt; 18">
</model>
```

To the property valid_weight is controlled by this condition, and any control bound to valid weight will disappear when not relevant.